# Error creating JPA model Google App Engine (GAE) in Android studio

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, jpa

By follow this tutorial http://www.appsrox.com/android/tutorials/instachat/7/#20 I have tryed to create a GCM chat app for my project. The client project works well. However, in the Server project they using GAE and have used JPA/JPO also but they have worked in Eclipse so made me confuse that how JPA to set up the necessary Jars file in build.gradle.

My server and client project have no error show up but the result I got is not the same as tutorial. Besides, in the appengine.google.com Logs a have the following Error lines:

```
Error for /send
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class    com.myapp.chat.backend.model.EMFService
 at   com.myapp.chat.backend.SendServlet.doPost(SendServlet.java:41)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
 ...
```

This  error refers to the following lines:

SendServlet.java

```
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String msg = req.getParameter(ServerConstants.MSG);
    String from = req.getParameter(ServerConstants.FROM);
    String to = req.getParameter(ServerConstants.TO);

    Contact contact = null;
    EntityManager em = EMFService.get().createEntityManager();
    try {
        contact = Contact.find(to, em);
        if (contact == null) return;
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }

    String regId = contact.getRegId();
    Sender sender = new Sender(ServerConstants.API_KEY);
    Message message = new Message.Builder()
        .addData(ServerConstants.TO, to).addData(ServerConstants.FROM, from).addData(ServerConstants.MSG, msg)
        .build();

    try {
        Result result = sender.send(message, regId, 5);     
        logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Result: " + result.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

My Contact.java file:

```
public class Contact {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String email;
private String regId;

public Contact() {}

public Contact(String email, String regId) {
    this.email = email;
    this.regId = regId;
}

public static Contact find(String email, EntityManager em) {
    Query q = em.createQuery("select c from Contact c where c.email = :email");
    q.setParameter("email", email);
    List<Contact> result = q.getResultList();

    if (!result.isEmpty()) {
        return result.get(0);
    }
    return null;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
public String getRegId() {
    return regId;
}
public void setRegId(String regId) {
    this.regId = regId;
}

}
```

My EMFService.java have the following lines:

```
public class EMFService {
    private static final EntityManagerFactory emfInstance = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("transactions-optional");

    private EMFService() {
    }

    public static EntityManagerFactory get() {
        return emfInstance;
    }

    private static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return EMFService.get().createEntityManager();
    }
}
```

My build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.18'
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter();
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

dependencies {
    appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.18'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.18'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.18'
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
    compile files('libs/javax.persistence-2.0.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/gcm-server.jar')
    compile 'jta:jta:1.0.1b'
    compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.appengine.orm:datanucleus-appengine:2.1.2'
    compile 'org.datanucleus:datanucleus-enhancer:3.1.1'
    compile 'javax.jdo:jdo2-api:2.3-eb'
    compile 'javax.transaction:jta:1.1'
    compile 'org.datanucleus:datanucleus-api-jdo:3.1.3' // WE NEED THIS
    compile 'org.ow2.asm:asm:4.0'
    compile 'org.datanucleus:datanucleus-api-jpa:3.1.3'
}

appengine {
enhancer {
    version = "v2"
    api="jdo"
    enhanceOnBuild = true
}
downloadSdk = true
appcfg {
    oauth2 = true
}
endpoints {
    getClientLibsOnBuild = true
    getDiscoveryDocsOnBuild = true
}
}
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.5">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Register</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.myapp.chat.backend.RegisterServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Register</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/register</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Unregister</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.myapp.chat.backend.UnregisterServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Unregister</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/unregister</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Send</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.myapp.chat.backend.SendServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Send</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/send</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>services</param-name>
        <param-value>com.myapp.chat.backend.MyEndpoint</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">

<persistence-unit name="transactions-optional">
    <provider>org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalRead" value="true"/>
        <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalWrite" value="true"/>
        <property name="datanucleus.ConnectionURL" value="appengine"/>
        <property name="datanucleus.appengine.datastoreEnableXGTransactions" value="true" />
        <property name="datanucleus.appengine.autoCreateDatastoreTxns" value="true" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Because I'm using different IDE I'm not sure where I Put each file. However when I click "Deploy App Engine" everything works fine. Please anybody help me how to fix the debug. Thanks!

Comment: when are you getting this error?

Comment: When i try to send a message via SendServlet.java. I update my question whit the entire class that generate error.